# Django: How to get parameters used in filter() from a QuerySet?

Tags: django

For the following QuerySet,

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(attribute_one='value 1', attribute_two='value 2')
```

How can I retrieve the parameters used in the filter (i.e. `attribute_one` and `attribute_two`) and the corresponding values (i.e. `value 1` and `value 2`) from `qs`?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried this `qs = MyModel.objects.filter(attribute_one='value 1', attribute_two='value 2').values('attribute_one','attribute_two')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) as mentioned in comment. From the docs:

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(
   attribute_one='value 1', attribute_two='value 2'
).values('attribute_one', 'attribute_two')

for q in qs:
  for key, value in q.items():
    # key as attribute_one
    # value as value_1
    # and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through it, even though there only may be one item in qs.

```
    for i in qs:
        print(i.value1)

    or just do...

    for qs in MyModel.objects.filter(
        attribute_one='value 1', attribute_two='value 2'):

        print(qs.value1)

    Alternatively if it is one object you are after use 'get'

    MyModel.objects.get(
        attribute_one='value 1', attribute_two='value 2')
```